# How to use showkeys with hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, incompatibility, showkeys

The ["ChangeLog for hyperref bundle"](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/ChangeLog.pdf) file claims that support for the [`showkeys`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showkeys) package was added to [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) in various stages on 2000-05-08, 2001-01-27, and 2007-05-29.  However, there still seem to be some incompatibilities between the two packages.  Furthermore, some strange interactions occur depending on which of the two packages is loaded first.

Consider the following MWE, where `showkeys` is loaded before `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{New Section}
\label{some-label}

This is a really important section.

Now we want to refer to~\autoref{some-label} on \autopageref{some-label}.

What if we just refer to section~\ref{some-label} on page~\ref{some-label}?
This seems to work fine.

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{abc}
    This book has no title.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

First of all, it appears that the `\autopageref` command has no support for package `showkeys`, as the label is not printed.  Next, with this example, the `\bibitem` key is not printed either.

On the other hand, suppose we reverse the package loading order, and load `hyperref` before `showkeys`.  In this case, the key for `\bibitem` is displayed correctly, but now `\autopageref` is totally broken:  The page number is missing from the output text, replaced by `??some-label`, and the following warning is written:

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `*' on page 1 undefined on input line 28.
```

So when I prepare my draft documents, I'm stuck having to choose between having the `\bibitem` keys not shown or having `\autopageref` totally broken.  I can live with the `\autopageref` keys not being shown, as long as the output is the correct text (`showkeys` before `hyperref`), but I really want to have the `\bibitem` keys shown (`hyperref` before `showkeys`) so that I can copy the labels into citations when typing the rest of the document.  How can I correct one or the other of these problems to get the best of both scenarios?

Answer (score 3):

The `hyperref` manual states in Section 8:

> Packages that typeset the contents of the \label and \ref macros, such as showkeys. Since the
>   hyperref package redefines these commands, you must set implicit=false for these packages
>   to work.

Your example appears to work for me if the document starts as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage[implicit=false]{hyperref}
```

Comment: But then the hyperlinks disappear, defeating the purpose of loading `hyperref`.  Moreover, `\autoref` and `\autopageref` both produce only the number `1`, rather than the intended `section 1` and `page 1` (respectively).